# error in including "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat" during conversion using pyinstaller in macos

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, dlib

I have a code using dlib module in python, two lines in the code are

```
predictor_path = "./shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)
```

the whole code runs fine in python interpreter.
When I try to convert it to executable using pyinstaller, I put the "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat" file name in the data field of .spec file
i.e.

```
a = Analysis(...
             binaries=[],
             datas=[("./shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat", ".")]
             ...)
```

The process completes without any error. The .dat file also gets included in the folder. But when I run the executable file it shows error

```
RuntimeError: Unable to open ./shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
[928] Failed to execute script new_run
...
```

If I put that .dat file in the binaries field in .spec file it shows error during conversion -

```
ValueError: Unknown Mach-O header: 0x01018188 in <_io.BufferedReader 
name='/Users/mac/Library/Application 
Support/pyinstaller/bincache00_py37_64bit/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat'>
```

I am using macOS, and python 3.6 the whole code runs fine in the python interpreter but this problem arising during the conversion.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi i've ran into the same issue in win10, any change??

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding face recognition binaries in the spec file like so:

```
face_models = [
('venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\face_recognition_models\\models\\dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat', './face_recognition_models/models'),
('venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\face_recognition_models\\models\\mmod_human_face_detector.dat', './face_recognition_models/models'),
('venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\face_recognition_models\\models\\shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat', './face_recognition_models/models'),
('venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\face_recognition_models\\models\\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat', './face_recognition_models/models'),
]


a = Analysis(['fac-rec.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Dell\\source\\python\\face-rec'],
             binaries=face_models,
             datas=[],
```

as suggested in [this](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/357) post